# Hosting for javadoc?

Tags: java, open-source, hosting, javadoc, bitbucket

I have an open source project hosted on [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/). Bitbucket does not provide hosting for large number of small files (i. e. javadocs). Where could I publish javadocs? Javadocs must be browseable, not as single archive.

Comment: Checkout this one too - https://docshoster.org/
The differentiation is good search even for older javadoc versions and a different style of documentation menu.

Answer (score 15):

If your open source project is released to central maven repo, then you can use [javadoc.io](http://www.javadoc.io) to host your javadoc.

Your javadoc will be under: http://www.javadoc.io/doc/$groupId/$artifactId

For example: http://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-core

I find it convenient because javadoc.io will automatically pick up latest version when there is a newer version released to central maven repo.

Comment: It looks great, but for some reason it's not picking up all projects properly (such as [simple-java-mail](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codemonkey.simplejavamail%7Csimple-java-mail%7C2.5.1%7Cjar)).

Comment: The searching functionality is badly implemented. But the pattern is simple. For simple-java-mail you can use this direct link: http://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.codemonkey.simplejavamail/simple-java-mail

Answer (score 5):

Do it on BitBucket! You can [host a static file web site](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/publishing-a-website-on-bitbucket-cloud-221449776.html) there.

Answer (score 2):

[amazon s3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), but it is not free.

Comment: Amazon s3 seems to be expensive for large number of small files.

Comment: It does?  I don't see where there is a per file charge.  Perhaps it is expensive if you are getting tons of hits, but I don't see where you've said that is an issue?

Comment: $0.01 per 10,000 GET requests. It seems not so much as I thought before.